# 2 PHP Installations - how to configure?

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, iis-7, xampp

I have a windows server 2003 with ISS 7.0. There runs 2 sites with simple php, which I have installed easily. (C:/Program Files/PHP)

Now I install XAMPP for MYSQL and XAMPP installed a second (inactive) PHP (C:/XAMPP/PHP).

How to change from my installed PHP to XAMPP PHP (It's newer and a few extensions I wanna use it's in there allready) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to switch entirely to the new PHP instance for IIS, then you need to create/use a registry key HKLM\Software\PHP\IniFilePath (String Value) with the directory where the PHP.INI file resides for your new PHP version.

If you want two different PHP instances for two sites in IIS then you might be able to do this with two application pools, but I suspect that could be tricky.

Otherwise you could use Apache and provide the PHPIniDir directive in the httpd.conf for each Apache instance you want to use a different PHP version for.